# Sending argument from CGI script as bash script argument

Tags: linux, bash, shell, csh

I am trying to pass the argument to my bash script through my cgi script. This may sound a little bit confusing, so here is the explanation,

I have bash script called `script.sh` which accept one argument lets say `name`
so I execute this script like this,

`bash script.sh myName`

The name is then written in a text file, and then i can read it from that text file.

Which works just fine, but I want to be able to execute this same command through  cgi, so I did this inside my cgi file,

```
`/bin/echo "bash script.sh myName"`;
```

Now I execute this cgi script through my webserver like this,

```
http://localhost/index.cgi
```

but `myName` is not passing as an argument to my bash script and hence nothing is written on the text file.

Can anyone please tell me why its not working when I am running through cgi script but working fine when run without a cgi script ?

**EDIT:** I have also tried using `exec()` but the argument still wouldn't pass.

Comment: In what programming language the CGI script is written?

Comment: `#!/bin/csh` so its C-shell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the comments to the question you wrote that the CGI script was written in CSH.

Then it's as simple as the following.

**script.csh**

```
#!/bin/csh
./script.sh argX
```

**script.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
echo 'hello,' $1
```

**Testing script.csh**

```
./script.csh 
hello, argX
```

It it isn't what you are looking for, please clarify.

Comment: suppose `abcd` is written in a text file, my bash script accept an argument and modify the value of `abcd` with that argument. when i run `./index.cgi` it does it perfectly. but when i run it through webserver i.e `http://localhost/index.cgi` that doesn't happen, i.e. text file still says `abcd`.

Comment: do you have write permission to that directory ?

Comment: @RileyWillow, which server software are you running(Nginx, Apache, etc)? Is there something in the logs?

Comment: writing to `/tmp/` directory